# Async AWS Lambda not executed if caller returns too early

Tags: aws-lambda

I'm trying to call an async lambda function from *within* another lambda function, and I'm finding that it doesn't get executed if the calling function exits too quickly.

In other words, the following doesn't ever work. LambdaFunction2 never gets called.

```
function lambdaFunction1(event, context) {
  callLambdaFunction2();
  context.done(null);
}
```

But adding a small delay before LambdaFunction1 exits does tend to work so far:

```
function lambdaFunction1(event, context) {
  callLambdaFunction2();
  setTimeout(
    function() {
     context.done(null);
    }, 500
  );
}
```

What concerns me is that waiting 500ms is a rather arbitrary magic number. Has anyone encountered a similar problem and found a more principled fix?

Answer (score 5):

`callLambdaFunction2()` probably does not complete before `context.done(null)` causes handler to exit.

To fix this you would need to call `context.done` as a callback. For example:

```
lambda.invoke({
    FunctionName: "functionName",
    InvocationType: 'Event',
    Payload: JSON.stringify(event)
}, function(err, data) {
    if (err) return context.done(err, null);
    return context.done(null, data);
});
```

If this is not the solution, can you show how you have implemented `callLambdaFunction2`?