# Lambda AWS not calling node mysql callbacks

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to process bounces sent from Amazon's Simple Email Service via their Simple Notification Service vi a Lambda on AWS.

I'm running the following script:

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');

var mysql = require('mysql');

Processor = {};

Processor.initializeConnection = function() {
        console.log('Connecting to database');
        Processor.connection = mysql.createConnection({
          host   : 'MYHOST',
          user   : 'MYUSER',
          password : 'PASSWORD',
          database : 'DATABASE'
        });
        console.log('Connection configured');
        Processor.connection.connect(function(err) {
                console.log('****');
                console.log(err);
                if (err != null) {
                        console.log('Could not connect to database');
                        return false;
                } else {
                        console.log('Successfully connected to database');
                        return true;
                }
        });

        console.log('Should not get here');
};

exports.handler = function(event,context){
        console.log('Received event:');
        var message = event.Records[0].Sns.Message;

        // Get the object from the event and show its content type

        if(Processor.initializeConnection()) {
                context.fail('Database connection failed');
                return;
        }

    context.succeed(message);
};
```

I upload this script as index.js along with node_modules containing the node mysql module all as a zip file.

I get the following output from Amazon when this is run:

```
START RequestId: 378b8a8c-30d4-11e5-9db4-9b9537e3f53d 
2015-07-23T00:46:13.159Z    378b8a8c-30d4-11e5-9db4-9b9537e3f53d    Received event: 
2015-07-23T00:46:13.160Z    378b8a8c-30d4-11e5-9db4-9b9537e3f53d    Connecting to database 
2015-07-23T00:46:14.035Z    378b8a8c-30d4-11e5-9db4-9b9537e3f53d    Connection configured 
2015-07-23T00:46:14.095Z    378b8a8c-30d4-11e5-9db4-9b9537e3f53d    Should not get here 
END RequestId: 378b8a8c-30d4-11e5-9db4-9b9537e3f53d 
REPORT RequestId: 378b8a8c-30d4-11e5-9db4-9b9537e3f53d  Duration: 937.51 ms Billed Duration: 1000 ms Memory Size: 128 MB    Max Memory Used: 14 MB
```

None of the code inside the connect fallback is run. I'm expecting it to report a connection failure as I'm not using valid credentials.

If I run a version of the code locally under nodejs the connect callback does fire. It just doesn't fire under Lambda.

Comment: Your callbacks are structured incorrectly. You need to pass your callback inside initializeConnection() and call it from inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the asynchronous nature of node.js, your code might be exiting as a result of `context.succeed()` before all of your functions are executed.

See:

- [Async AWS Lambda not executed if caller returns too early](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30857201/async-aws-lambda-not-executed-if-caller-returns-too-early)
- [Why is this HTTP request not working on AWS Lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28449363/why-is-this-http-request-not-working-on-aws-lambda)